# Site css compatibility with IE 7 not working

Tags: css, browser, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Thanks for checking out my post. I am currently re-skinning a html5 template for my employer and have noticed while doing a bit of QA that the site appears to come out completely wrong on ie7 and 8. It seems as if the css styles are not even being pushed to the page.

here is my test link: http://daniloportal.com/NPC/index.html

I have added a couple of ifIE7 ifIE8 lines to my head but doesn't seem to do the trick. Im a newbie when it comes to ie compatibility fix's - any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!
D

Comment: Please provide the code for where you are experiencing issues. Also, simply saying something "looks completely wrong" tell us nothing. The more information that you provide, the more feasible it is for people to assist you.

Comment: hey swordfish, the code is really the entire page... on other browsers it appears perfect minus the ie7 and 8 browsers. Im not sure if there is a specific block that would point out why

Comment: Did you try adding the doctype as @Adrift suggested?

Comment: yup i did, worked out super well! even the animations are running. Glad you all helped me out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a [**doctype**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) at the top of your file.

This just triggers IE to go into [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) which causes all sorts of problems. Put the doctype at the top of your file and make sure no-white space or comment precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

Put Doctype  and place IE condition at top

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Tamil thanks so much for your help, Adrift pointed me in the right direction first but your advice is also extremely helpful. Thanks for helping me figure out this stupid problem lol